# Filter inner element from a tree via lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm constantly admitting that I'm bad at lens, but isn't learning by examples is a good thing? I want to take HTML, parse it with `taggy-lens` and then remove all the `script` elements from inside. Here's my attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-7.1 --install-ghc runghc --package text --package lens --package taggy-lens --package string-class --package classy-prelude

{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import ClassyPrelude
import Control.Lens hiding (children, element)
import Data.String.Class (toText, fromText, toString)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Text.Taggy.Lens
import qualified Text.Taggy.Lens as Taggy
import qualified Text.Taggy.Renderer as Renderer

somehtmlSmall :: Text
somehtmlSmall =
    "<!doctype html><html><body>\
    \<div id=\"article\"><div>first</div><div>second</div><script>this should be removed</script><div>third</div></div>\
    \</body></html>"

renderWithoutScriptTag :: Text
renderWithoutScriptTag =
    let mArticle :: Maybe Taggy.Element
        mArticle =
            (fromText somehtmlSmall) ^? html .
            allAttributed (ix "id" . only "article")
        mArticleFiltered =
            fmap
                (\el ->
                      el ^.. to universe . traverse .
                      filtered (\n -> n ^. name /= "script"))
                mArticle
    in maybe "" (toText . concatMap Renderer.render) mArticleFiltered

main :: IO ()
main = print renderWithoutScriptTag
```

Mark this file as executable and just run it, and you'll see:

```
➜  tmp  ./scraping-question.hs
"<div id=\"article\"><div>first</div><div>second</div><script>this should be removed</script><div>third</div></div><div>first</div><div>second</div><div>third</div>"
```

So, this didn't work. I would like to:

- have a working solution
- understand the working solution

Would be especially thankful, if you'd help me realize what's wrong with mine. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much lens either, and I can't answer the question, but I would recommend pulling your code apart a bit more. Write a function that takes a `Taggy.Element` and produces a filtered `Taggy.Element`. Then write a separate function handling the conversion from/to text around that, which can probably be done pretty directly through the prism.

Comment: (Neat trick with the stack shebang -- very useful for Stack Overflow!)

Comment: I often find myself referring back the the FPComplete article on stack scripts to get all the options right: https://www.fpcomplete.com/haskell/tutorial/stack-script/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your problem is `universe`, which flattens the DOM tree into a list. If you look again at the output, you will see the filtering is working fine but the tree structure is lost -- and so you get the unmodified article element (with all children still within) followed by the children nodes minus the script element.

One `Control.Lens.Plated` combinator that can do what you want is [`transform`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:transform), which transforms "every element in the tree, in a bottom-up manner":

```
transform :: Plated a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

In particular, you can use it to filter the children nodes recursively:

```
renderWithoutScriptTag :: Text
renderWithoutScriptTag =
    let mArticle :: Maybe Taggy.Element
        mArticle =
            (fromText somehtmlSmall) ^? html .
            allAttributed (ix "id" . only "article")
        mArticleFiltered =
            fmap
                (transform (children %~ filter (\n ->
                    n ^? element . name /= Just "script")))
                mArticle
    in maybe "" (toText . Renderer.render) mArticleFiltered
```

Comment: Thank you! If you don't mind, added this for a review in SO Documentation http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/6962/parsing-html-with-taggy-lens-and-lens#t=201610051948271417687 (might be not visible until accepted)

Comment: @KostiantynRybnikov I don't mind at all -- reuse it as you see fit.